# What are the APIs of Media Recorder Application for Banana Pi BPI-W2?

Tags: python, android, raspberry-pi

I need to use Banana Pi BPI-W2 to get video streams from source. I am able to get videos using Banana-PI Media Recorder Application. I am now planning to use pydroid but i do not know about any API exposed to get this done using python. Let me know about any documentation or any thing about the problem.

P.S. banana-pi or pydroid tags are not listed on the stack exchange and i cannot create new tags with low reputations.

Comment: There is a banana-pi tag on stackoverflow.com, which is the Stack Exchange site for questions about programming problems. You should pose your question there if you haven't already.

Comment: They expect certain code snippet as problem to solve. Since question is very high level i can not post it there.

Comment: I think this is a misunderstanding. SO users will definitely want to see the code if you are asking about a specific problem related to a program you have written.  However this does not mean that all questions there require code; just look at the example on the tour page there: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: If its a typical Android application, I would say that it might be a stretch to assume it has any kind of API (unless you have solid reason to believe otherwise). If it saves files to the device, you will probably have to figure out where and what format they are in. If it runs on the command line with instructions or if it can broadcast to the network, those CLI options and URLs are likely what you will need to build any application around (including any Python scripts/programs). If it operates only via a GUI or specialized applications, you might be out of luck.